# 'I take no objection' or 'I have no objection'?

Tags: word-choice

Have vs. Take

Google Books indicates usage of 'take' though 'have' is perhaps more common, particularly in a legal setting: I have no objections, Your Honour.

Is there any difference between, for example:

1. I have no objection to your proposal
2. I take no objection to your proposal

or are they interchangeable?

Is it that 'take' can only be used in the singular? 'I take no objections, Your Honour' sounds ghastly.

Comment: I will not change it, as I do not feel that my question has actually changed.  My response to you, and my original question, make it clear that I am interested in understanding usage of 'I have no objection' vs. 'I take no objection'.

Comment: I would suggest that my first question is "'I take no objection' or 'I have no objection'?". As per the title. My second question relates purely to the example that I gave so as to aid in answering the first question. Thankfully,  another user has attempted to assist me and correctly understood what it is that I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion here is due to counting. **"To take objection"** is a verb phrase, and is synonymous with "**to object"**; it does not count a number of objections.

However, if you want to count a number of objections (and "no", "none" and "zero" are all counting) then you use the verb **"to have"**.

Hence it is:

> I *take* objection to that!
>
> I *have an* objection to that!
>
> I *don't take* objection to that.
>
> I *have no* objection to that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you're right - counting is the issue here. Are you insisting that 'I take no objection' would be an incorrect form? I only ask as there is evidence of its usage in British and Canadian Parliamentary proceedings (e.g. 'I take no objection; it is sufficiently clear and explicit' or 'I take no objection to that, that is a mere matter of opinion.'). Is this usage incorrect, in your opinion?

Comment: I do think it is "incorrect". But it does get used a bit (e.g. see [this ngrams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+no+objection%2Chave+no+objection%2Ctake+objection&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20no%20objection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20no%20objection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20objection%3B%2Cc0)), and English isn't set in stone, it morphs. (i.e. if enough people say something it becomes "correct" by default).

Answer (score 0):

On a comparative view the difference between the two would be that "I take no objection to your proposal" indicates that you may have an objection but you are choosing not to state it. Whereas, "I have no objection to your proposal" indicates that you have no objection whatsoever. However, this understanding of the phrases only occurs if you compare the two.

Another view is "I take no objection to your proposal" may indicate a slightly more personal view of the proposal. This is because the term "taking objection" something is generally used when someone personally takes offence or personally objects to something. Whereas "I have no objection to your proposal" is slightly less personal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would certainly agree that 'taking objection' has more of a personal tone to it.