# Is "take disagreement with" a phrase? If not, what am I thinking of?

Tags: phrases, expressions

For example, "I do take disagreement with [find something I oppose in] certain parts of his speech".

What I'm thinking of is in the format of "I take offense at", but about opposing something. Similar to "dispute".

Comment: The simple way is _I disagree with that_. If you insist on using a noun, _I have a disagreement with that_ or _I am in disagreement with that_ are OK. Not _take_.

Comment: I think I have the answer: I do take exception to [some things]

Comment: Take objection to was what I was looking for.

Comment: _Take exception to_ is idiomatic; *_take objection to_ is not. You can object (stress on JECT) to something, or you can have an objection to it, or you can make an objection or post an objection in some official way, like in a court.

Comment: I may have heard it once or twice, but it's not idiomatic.

Comment: @JohnLawler https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286437/i-take-no-objection-or-i-have-no-objection/286444 Admittedly I can't find it anywhere else on Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would say "I take *issue with* certain parts of his speech".

Taking issue with something means that you disagree in some way with what's been said. Normally you'd then go on to explain what elements of an argument you have a problem with.

Comment: I believe that was what I was thinking of.